# how to execute a command only on the 3rd file of each folders

Tags: linux, data

I have sub folders which contain 3 .txt files. Is it possible to choose only the 3rd file of each sub folder? Actually I want to copy and rename/add"e" at the end of each filename.Only on 3rd file of each folder. 
this is the foldering

`New folder/20130903/ELF`:

```
Naqs_20130901.txt
Naqs_20130902.txt
Naqs_20130903.txt
```

`New folder/20130904/ELF`:

```
Naqs_20130902.txt
Naqs_20130903.txt
Naqs_20130904.txt
```

and i will only do it in 3rd file

Comment: Since there are exactly three files per directory, just pick the last one: ``for d in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do last=$(ls "$d" | tail -1);  echo mv "$d/${last}" "$d/${last}e"; done`` (remove the ``echo`` to actually perform the rename operation). This uses the default lexical sorting of ``ls``, so YMMV.

Comment: What do you mean the third folder, that is arbitrary based on how you are sorting them.?

Comment: I mean I have mutiple folders which contain 3 text file each folder and i will add e at the end of filename of every 3rd file inside the folder.

Comment: Yes, but how are you deciding which is the third folder... ?

Comment: How are you deciding which is the 3rd *file*?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention. each folder contains files like these 20120101.txt, 20120102.txt,20120103.txt. in this case i must choose only the 3rd/last file which is 20120103.txt because i only need the data for that date

Comment: @p_p can you please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/293715/edit) and post directory structure in your question. For e.g, `ls -l /folder`

Comment: @p_p that means `Naqs_20130903.txt` & `Naqs_20130904.txt` on these files ?

Comment: @Rahul Yes Naqs_20130903.txt & Naqs_20130904.txt

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `bash`, this can be done by filename expansion inside an array:

```
for dir in New\ folder/20130903/ELF New\ folder/20130904/ELF ; do
    files=( "$dir"/* )   # store all matching filenames in an array
    echo "${files[2]}"    # use 3rd element (subscripts are 0-based)
done
```

This outputs

```
New folder/20130903/ELF/Naqs_20130903.txt
New folder/20130904/ELF/Naqs_20130904.txt
```

Replace the `echo` line with whatever command you need to run on those files:

```
mv "${files[2]}" "${files[2]}e"
```

Comment: this works but it only works if i write  "20130903/ELF" "20130904/ELF". What if i also have folders with 20130905 and many more, is there a way it can see all folders with 2013????. I tried to edit your command using your "2013????/ELF" instead of using 20130903 and 20130904 but i think it can 't read it.

Comment: I put those in quotes because of the space in `New folder`, but that prevents filename expansion (using the `?` or `*` wildcards).  I've edited to escape the space instead - so `New\ folder/2013????/ELF` should work.  Alternatively, you could quote only the bit with a space: `"New folder/"2013????/ELF`